# JQuery Form Validation Does Nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, validation

This code isn't doing anything when I submit the form. What am I doing wrong? In the HTML, an error message is shown or hidden based on a class.

I hope you can help me figure out this problem. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validateForm() {
    var first_name = $("#first_name").value;
    var last_name = $("#last_name").value;
    var phone = $("#phone").value;
    var email = $("#email").value;
    var code = $("#vali_code").value;
    var ssn = $("#ssn").value;
    var income = $("#nm_income").value;
    var error = $(this).find("span.error_txt").removeClass(".hidden").addClass(".show");

    var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (first_name === "") {
      error;
    }

    if (last_name === "") {
      error;
    }

    if (email === "" || email !== emailReg) {
      error;

    }

    if (phone === "" || phone < 9) {
      error;
    }

    if (ssn === "" || ssn > 4) {
      error;
    }

    if (income === "") {
      error;
    }

    if (code === "") {
      error;
    }

    return true;
  }

});
```

Comment: Show us the HTML Code too.

Comment: Where this `validateForm` function is called?

Comment: why don't you use `jquery.validate` library for this purpose. It will make your life easier a lot.

Comment: Include your `HTML` also.

Comment: You should declare `function validateForm() { ... }` out of `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the function in inline event `onsubmit` you should add `return` keyword to the function call in your form  inline event like :

```
<form onsubmit='return validateForm()'>
```

But I think the main problem comes from the `.value` in your code it should be replaced by `.val()` since the `value` isn't an attribute of jQuery objects.

My suggestion is to attach the submit event in the JS code like the snippet below.

**NOTE:** The argument passed to`removeClass()` and `addClass()` methods shouldn't contains dot `.` at the start.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', validateForm);
})

function validateForm() {
  var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
  var last_name = $("#last_name").val();

  $(this).find("span.error_txt").removeClass("hidden").addClass("show");

  if (first_name === "") {
    return false;
  }

  if (last_name === "") {
    return false;
  }

  alert('Form will be submited.');
  return true;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id='first_name'><br>
  <input id='last_name'><br>

  <button>Submit</button>
  <span class="error_txt hidden">Error occurred check you form fields again.</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `return false` in case the form is invalid, otherwise it will be submitted.

Comment: The OP already has many mistakes, so returning `false` won't solve his issue.